# How do I add 2 columns in influxdb?

Tags: influxdb

I have series s1 (e.g. host 1) with 2 columns cA (e.g. memory used) and cB (e.g. another type of memory used), respectively.

How do I get a set of points which are the result of adding s1.cA and s1.cB.

I've looked at the influxdb documentation here http://influxdb.com/docs/v0.7/api/query_language.html
but I couldn't understand their examples.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to run `select cA + cB from s1`, below is a screenshot of running the query on some sample data:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, does this work even if the timestamps from the two columns don't line up exactly with each other?

Comment: I could not get this to work if a 'row' does not have data for all the columns being added. My series name is mem_usage, and each column is data from a different server. Since each server sends in stats independently, they will have different time stamps. One row will only have server1 data, and another row will only have server 2 data. I could not get those to add (I get back no results). Should this work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just used this: median(cA)+median(cB) to group by time, that would force align the timestamps (of course, you can use something more appropriate than median to your use case)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to add data from different sources having different timestamp, you could follow the below steps -

```
Source A

1. Set the time series name
2. Set the coulmns (2 in your case)
3. Set the point of Source A, set 0 for source B

Source B

1. Set the time series name
2. Set the coulmns (2 in your case)
3. Set the point of Source B, set 0 for source A
```

JSON request with the data will look something like below -

```
{"name":"s1","columns":["cA","cB"],"points":[[0,1212],[123123123,0]]}
```